# Node.js: Responding base64 encoded images into a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, base64

I have in my database all pictures in **base64** with extra data (creation, likes, owner, etc).

And I want to implement a **`/pictures GET`** that return a JSON with pictures data, ex:

**Pictures data**

```
[{
   "creation": 1479567470124,
   "data": "data:image/jpg;base64,R0lGODlhPQ...",
   "ownerId": "cbd4dd05-193c-4e93-8e76-cae055adb046",
   "likes": 23
},
{
   "creation": 1479566234367,
   "data": "data:image/jpg;base64,A0dFSfdsf34SD...",
   "ownerId": "24170e4d-246f-4c77-b493-a56bde870169",
   "likes": 4
}]
```

**Api route**

```
app.get('/pictures', (req, res) => {
    const { last, limit } = req.query;

    db.getPictures(last, limit)
    .then(pictures => res.status(201).jsonp(pictures))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
});
```

### Problem

The problem is that the **data field** (field that contain the base64 encoded image) is so **HUGE**. And is not possible to send a huge json into the response.

My question is how to do it... Is there any way? Maybe in a stream? How?

Any suggestion will be great

*Note: The images should be saved as base64 encoded into the database (company requeriment)*

Thank you very much!

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I don't remember!! hehe Quite a time ago

Comment: I can understand. hahaha... Is it fine if I serve my images static? I have done like this now.

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember. I asked this in stackoverflow almost 4 years ago, I don't remember the context and what solution I applied.

Comment: Totally fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use streams.

This example uses file but it is easy to make it working with something else.

https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-streams/

---

#### Edits

No, you can't use `application/json`, your response type should be `arraybuffer`. Then, because you know how the data is, parse the response with a json parser...

In my opinion the best way to do what you need is *split the response*.

Build two different APIs, the first that is a pure json api and returns all the metadata of the picture and the second one that returns the image as a stream.
The final part of the job belongs to the client that needs to merge the two responses.

Comment: And is it possible to send a JSON only with the data field like a stream, or I need to send the JSON like a stream? And if both are possible, which is better? Thank you